# How to efficiently support a large client number on a python udp server with concurreny

Tags: python, performance, concurrency, network-programming

The code is a udp server that does two things on two different threads. The first thread will use select to monitor a list of udp sockets for data(ip packets) and will call a method (on_pack2()) to a new thread every time there is data received. The second thread will continuously read ip packets from a virtual tun device and will call a method (send_pack2()) on a new thread every time there is data.

```
from . import tun, ip, net

class socket_addr_store:
    def __init__(self,sock,client_addr):
        self.sock = sock
        self.client_addr = client_addr


class Server:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.online_client = []
        self.online_client_sock = {}
        self.reads = []
        self.writes = []
        self.pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(10)
        
        for port in range(9093,9097):
            self._sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
            self._sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            self._addr = ('0.0.0.0', port)
            self._sock.setblocking(0)
            self._sock.bind(self._addr)
            self.reads.append(self._sock)
        self._threads = []
        self._tun_dev = None
        
        # creating client ip pool
        self._addr_allocator = net.AddrAllocator('10.0.0.0/24')
        

    def route_traffic_to(self, tun_dev: tun.Device) -> 'Server':
        self._tun_dev = tun_dev
        return self

    def start(self) -> None:
        self._tun_read_thread = Thread(target=self.on_tun_recv2)
        self._tun_read_thread.start()

        while True:
            readeables,writeables,Exceptions=select.select(self.reads,self.writes,self.writes)
            for s in readeables:
                packet, addr = s.recvfrom(4096)
                if packet:
                    self.pool.submit(self.on_pack2,packet,addr,s)
                    # self.on_pack2(packet,addr,s)

    
                   
    def on_tun_recv2(self) -> None:
        while True:
            packet = self._tun_dev.read()
            self.pool.submit(self.send_pack2,packet)
            # self.send_pack2(packet)
                
    def send_pack2(self,packet)->None:
        dst_ip_add = ip.dst_addr(packet)
        if dst_ip_add in self.online_client:
            if dst_ip_add in self.online_client_sock:
                sock = self.online_client_sock[dst_ip_add].sock
                add = self.online_client_sock[dst_ip_add].client_addr
                sock.sendto(packet,add)
    
    def on_pack2(self,packet:bytes,client_addr:net.Address,s) ->None:
        try:
            
            x = packet[0]
        except Exception as e:
            pass
        else:
                
            if x not in (0,1,2):
                # print("normal pack")
                # Check if its from a client online before write to tun device
                src_ip = ip.src_addr(packet)
                if src_ip in self.online_client:
                    self.online_client_sock[src_ip] = socket_addr_store(s,client_addr)
                    self._tun_dev.write(packet)
            elif x == 0:
                if len(packet) > 4:
                    # print("its auth")
                    # we auth the client and provide an address
                    
                    shared_secret = packet.decode()[1:]
                    # print(shared_secret)
                    # TO-DO we authenticate the shared secret before we obtain an tunnel ip 

                    new_tun_ip = self._addr_allocator.new(shared_secret)
                    if new_tun_ip != "serverfull":
                        mtu = "m,1500"
                        # add_adr = "a,10.0.0.1,24"
                        add_adr = f"a,{str(new_tun_ip)},24"
                        add_route = "r,0.0.0.0,0"
                        add_dns = "d,8.8.8.8"
                        add_search_domain = "s,dns.google.com"
                        client_auth = f"{mtu} {add_adr} {add_route} {add_dns} {add_search_domain}".encode()
                        # client_auth_append = b'0'+client_auth
                        client_auth_append = b'\x00'+client_auth

                        # packta = str(new_tun_ip).encode()
                        self.online_client.append(new_tun_ip)
                        s.sendto(client_auth_append,client_addr)
                    else:
                        #serfull
                        s.sendto(b'\x02',client_addr)  
            elif x == 1:
                # print("its deauth") 
                #we release the ip and offline the client 
                shared_secret = packet.decode()[1:]
                tun_ip_d = self._addr_allocator.get_address(shared_secret)
                if tun_ip_d is not None:
                    if tun_ip_d in self.online_client:
                        self.online_client.remove(tun_ip_d)
                    if tun_ip_d in self.online_client_sock:
                        del self.online_client_sock[tun_ip_d] 
                    self._addr_allocator.release(shared_secret)   
            elif x == 2:
                # we update the sending socket
                src_our_client_ip = packet.decode()[1:]
                # print(f"we update the sending socket {src_our_client_ip} ")
                if src_our_client_ip in self.online_client:
                    self.online_client_sock[src_our_client_ip] = socket_addr_store(s,client_addr)
```

The code utilizes threadpoolexecutor to open new threads. would this be a way having in mind the server has to handle at-least 5000 clients or Would using asyncio have a better performance  scalability and efficiency.

Machine resources

```
max_workers as per threadpoolexecutor of my machine = 10
number of cpu's = 4
```

i hope to get a machine(VPS) with better resources

Comment: Python threads are not efficient because of the GIL and make things often more complex (manual locking is still required in some cases). In fact, using 1 thread per client is even known to be inefficient without the GIL (even with a small amount of client and select). You need to use better functions like epoll/kqueue which are system-dependent or a library abstracting that. IDK if the async feature provided in python help for performance though. Note that Python is clearly not great for such usage : it introduce a significant latency and throughput overhead, especially for UDP.